# Spring - Using @Resource over @Autowired for better performance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm using Spring with mostly `@Autowired` annotations

I read [@Autowired Vs @Resource](https://jira.spring.io/projects/SPR/issues/SPR-13086?filter=allopenissues) answers which basically state they have different flow order

> @Autowired and @Inject
>
> - Matches by Type
>
> -Restricts by Qualifiers
>
> -Matches by Name
>
> @Resource
>
> -Matches by Name
>
> -Matches by Type
>
> -Restricts by Qualifiers (ignored if match is found by name)

But should be the same

> Both @Autowired (or @Inject) and @Resource work equally well. But there is a conceptual difference or a difference in the meaning

But I stumbled on [SPR-13086
Autowiring with @Autowired/@Inject get much slower than with @Resource](https://jira.spring.io/projects/SPR/issues/SPR-13086?filter=allopenissues) which  is stating the `@Resource` has much better performance:

> @Inject and @Autowired (Pattern 1-4) seems to take O(N^2) time.
>   On the other hand @Resource seems to take O(N) time.

Is switching to using `@Resource` would result in better performance always and is really effecting significantly runtime performance?

Comment: Autowiring happens at startup. Runtime performance doesn't care how the dependencies have been injected into each other.

Comment: @JBNizet So I need to change only if I want to optimize my application startup?

Comment: By the time you have enough beans for  that issue to have a significant impact on your startup time, the problem will probably have been fixed. But yes, this only affects startup time.

Comment: @JBNizet agreed! Unless you have late bindings on the Beans then it matters otherwise its only startup cost you are paying for.